# Receiving Undefined on XML request

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

This is in my login.js but its receiving undefined from the server, whereas server is fetching correct data from the database when i check it manually.

```
request.open('GET', 'http://akshatbhargava123.imad.hasura-app.io/', true);
request.send(null);

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        // Take some action
        if(request.status === 200) {
            //alert('recieved');
            a = request.responceText;
            alert(a);
        }
    }
};
```

Here's my server's code segment:

```
var pool = new Pool(config);

app.get('/users' , function(req, res){
pool.query('SELECT * from users', function(err, results) {
 if(err){
     res.status(500).send(err.toString());
 }
 else{
     res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(results.rows[0].name));
 }
});
});
```

When I goto myapp/users, I receive correct data, i.e. "user1"

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's `responseText`, not `responceText`.

Comment: Omg such a silly mistake done by me, I thank you very much and will take care of these kinds of mistakes before posting next time.